# Accessing command's argument in auto-completion function in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I wish to create a custom command which has it's first argument as a regex & pressing `TAB` after typing regex will open a auto-complete menu with all the files matching the pattern.

if I name my command `vimf` (meaning vim find) and write the auto-complete function like:

```
#compdef vimf

_arguments "1: :_files -g \"**/*.conf\""\
```

In the above auto-complete function, typing $vimf  , lists all the files ending with `.conf` in the auto-completion menu. Now, I want this part `.conf` to be taken from the first argument of the command. So, if I type something like: `vimf *.pp`, I want it to search only files ending with `*.pp`.

How do I make that possible? How can I use the arguments of a command while writing auto-complete functions?

Comment: hey @shadyabhi, did you add the opportunity to try it? :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use the `words` array which is set to the content of the command line.

From this, you retrieve the file type by accessing the good index, and troncate the prefix. (this is done by `#compdef vimf`)

Here is the result:

```
#compdef vimf

_arguments "1: :_files -g \"**/*.${words[2]##*.}\""\
           && return 0
```

I tried it on my terminal, it works, but of course can take long time to perform if your do this by the root.  *Enjoy :)*